# Android android.graphics.Path width limited to 2036?

Tags: android, path, android-canvas

I am trying to draw a very long line with a Path. The line is correctly displayed up until to a x target value of 2036.

when i call path.lineTo(2037, y) the entire path is is not drawn. The call to canvas.drawPath(path, paint) does nothing.

Is there a problem i am not aware of?

On a second note... when i draw the same sequence of points via canvas.drawLines(float[], paint) the lines are correctly drawn but they are not antialiased. Is there a problem with antialiasing and drawLines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limitation with hardware acceleration: a Path can only be about 2048 pixels wide or high on most GPUs.

Line anti-aliasing should work as of Android 3.2 with hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying romain. Actually i am running against 3.1 so the anti aliasing does not work. It works correctly on 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Imho these limits would be described in these hundreds of lines that describe the difference of one version of Android from the other one.