# Limits of android.graphics.path

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I have a custom view which can zoom and pan. All it does is display a `path` (the coordinates of which are acquired from an API). Since `Path`s are uploaded as texture into the GPU and then drawn, there is a maximum limit on the dimension of the `path` that can be drawn (which varies from device to device). My custom view can grow pretty large (> 30000 pixels in area) and in order to get around the limitation, I have been using `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)` on my custom view. It's been working well but it doesn't help me in delivering 60FPS.

In order to bring the frame rate to 60FPS, I have decided to switch back to `LAYER_TYPE_NONE`. Now, instead of letting the path scale unchecked, I have decided to stop it at some particular zoom level and for further zooming, scale the `canvas` (at the loss of crispness). In order to find the zoom level at which I should stop scaling `path` and start scaling the `canvas`, I have been doing some trails (I am using nexus 7 (2012) and nexus 9 as test devices)

I expected to see the message `path too large to be rendered into a texture` only after hitting the texture size limit (which I find out using `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()`).

1. For nexus 7, the texture size limit is 2048, but the path disappears when its width or height hits [2036](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873242/android-android-graphics-path-width-limited-to-2036) & I see `path too large to be rendered into a texture` in the log. I expected this to happen at 2048!!
2. For nexus 9, the texture size limit is 16384, but sometimes the app crashes with the log `A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x78 in tid 7252 (RenderThread)` before even the texture limit is hit. For eg., these are some of the dimensions of the custom view when the app crashes: (7199, 5049), (13814, 2500), (8040, 4200). The only commonality I could find among those is that the total area of the custom view (and also the `path`) grows beyond 32,000,000 pixels.

Therefore, I couldn't decide when exactly I should switch from scaling `path` to scaling `canvas`. Any ideas as to when to do that?

**EDIT 1**

I observed that for nexus 9, the app crashes whenever the total area of the `path` reaches ~33,000,000. What does this limit signify?

Comment: Interesting question. It would be great to know max size for sure so that it is at least possible to code an helper for that.